# Part file is being null in my jsf app

Tags: jsf

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div align="center"><h:inputFile id="file" value="#{bb.file}" label="写真を選択"/></div><br />
    </h:form>



    public void toByteArray() throws IOException {
    if(file!=null){
    final ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    copy((InputStream) file, output);
    setBytes(output.toByteArray());
    } else {
        System.out.println("file = null");
    }
}
```

I'm tryin to put image into my database as byte[]. but in the first place file seems to be null I checked it in if(file!=null). but it doesnt seem I am doing wrong in xhtnl side. What on the earth is happening? 
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Here in Java code you have written 'if(file!=null)'.
Why you checked it as null. As the object you  are censidering is of File type object than just check that if it is file or not.

So i think you should write: if(file.isFile())

it will nullify your error